# Cannot convert value of type 'GraphRequestResult<GraphRequest>' to type '[Any]' in coercion

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the new facebook graph request:

```
let parameters = ["fields": "id, name, gender"]
                let nextrequest: GraphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: parameters, accessToken: AccessToken.current, httpMethod: .GET)

                nextrequest.start({ (response: HTTPURLResponse?, result: GraphRequestResult<GraphRequest>) in
             //   }) { (connection: GraphRequestConnection! , result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                    print(result as [Any])

})
```

I'm having a hard time parsing it I get this error:

Cannot convert value of type 'GraphRequestResult' to type '[Any]' in coercion

```
success(FacebookCore.GraphResponse(rawResponse: Optional({
    gender = male;
    id = 1128614937219535;
    name = "Rayan Slim";
})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the signature of the `GraphRequestResult`, in your case it is `(connection: GraphRequestConnection! , result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!)` maybe the Swift conversion is creating `(connection: GraphRequestConnection! , result: AnyObject?, error: Error?)`. i.e `NSError` -> `Error` and it is `Optional`.